# Android Replacing Thread.sleep with alarms using AlarmManager

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep, alarmmanager

I want to replace the `Thread.sleep(time)` calls in my code with alarms set with `AlarmManager`. How can I return to the proceeding code after the alarm has elapsed. It looks like I use a `PendingIntent` but how to I point it back to the proceeding code after the time has elapsed?.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on what values you have for `time`. If you are sleeping for 100ms, you definitely don't want to use `AlarmManager`, as piotrpo  suggests. However, if you are sleeping for several minutes, then `AlarmManager` is appropriate.

`AlarmManger` and `PendingIntents` impose big overheads, so be careful with using them.

Answer (score 1):

Alarm manager is not designed to something like that. `.sleep()` is also not good. Please read about Timer and Handler classes.